# Текстовый редактор Atom зависает

Tags: atom

Подскажите что происходит  текстовым редактором Atom?
Работаю, все ok? но через некоторое время он зависает, закрываю его, но потом он включается только после перезагрузки компа(кликаю по ярлыку, процесс запускается, но ничего не происходит). Перестановка Atom не помогает. Я так полагаю дело в компе
Оперативки 8 Гб
Процессор 3,7
Вроде все должно хватать. Но